# openmp 100 times slower than serial code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am using a node with 16 cores. But when I run the code is run in parallel it runs hundreds of times slower than the serial. I am unable to understand the reason. The parallel region is given below:

```
int Vector_mult_Matrix(vector<double> & vec, CTMC_matrix & ctmc_um)
{


     vector<double> res_vec(vec.size(),0);
      omp_set_num_threads(16);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(16)
    {
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait 
    for(size_t i=0; i<ctmc_um.trans_num; i++)
    {
    double temp = 0;
        temp = res_vec[ctmc_um.to_index[i]]+vec[ctmc_um.from_index[i]]*ctmc_um.rate[i];

    #pragma omp critical
    res_vec[ctmc_um.to_index[i]] = temp;
    }

}

vec.swap(res_vec);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I imagine that  cache receives some serious thrashing from sixteen threads pounding at different memory regions.

Comment: I am guessing that you are having some lock contention on that critical region

Comment: that critical section?

Comment: Please post a [mcve], your measurement methodology, your specific measurement results, and a more detailed system specification. And do format your code properly before submitting!

Comment: What compiler did you use and how did you time your code?

Comment: I used gcc and timed my code with omp_get_wtime()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why 100 times slower but it is slower due to reading/writing to the same memory regions, and multi thread requires this region to be locked else you will see race conditions. (If you were only reading no lock is required).

You are using `res_vec[ctmc_um.to_index[i]]` so even if openmp has split the indices with stride, your access index to `res_vec` might be tangled (result of `[ctmc_um.to_index[i]]`. Thus every other thread might need to wait for a thread to finish its job, and there are 16 of them.

Comment: Can you suggest what options can I try to make it faster?